# Time difference between 2 hours

Tags: javascript

I have beem looking for a code like this for a few days now. I did search a lot on the forum and found a bunch of threads about what I need but I couldn't get them to work (I have 0 expericnce in JS).
The code below does what I need, in a way.
It gives a negative value if the start time is, for example, 21:00 and the end time is 09:00.

Can anyone help me set it to positive? (I think it's related to beeing one day before, not sure thought).

```
<input type="time"  id="start" value="21:00" >
<input type="time" id="end" value="09:00" >

<input id="diff">


<script>
var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
var end = document.getElementById("end").value;

document.getElementById("start").onchange = function() {diff(start,end)};
document.getElementById("end").onchange = function() {diff(start,end)};


function diff(start, end) {
    start = document.getElementById("start").value; //to update time value in each input bar
    end = document.getElementById("end").value; //to update time value in each input bar
    
    start = start.split(":");
    end = end.split(":");
    var startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, start[0], start[1], 0);
    var endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, end[0], end[1], 0);
    var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    var hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);

    return (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
}

setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("diff").value = diff(start, end);}, 1000); //to update time every second (1000 is 1 sec interval and function encasing original code you had down here is because setInterval only reads functions) You can change how fast the time updates by lowering the time interval
</script>
```

PS: I found this code in here [Difference between two html time inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54658859/difference-between-two-html-time-inputs)

Thanks in advance,
eLy

Comment: Swap `start` and `end`?

Comment: `Math.abs(your expression)` for the absolute value.

Comment: what @Taplar said, use `abs()`

Comment: Taplar, what do I do with that? Sorry, but like I said, 0 experience in JS.

Comment: Probably `var diff = Math.abs(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime());`.  If you are going to be using javascript code, you should really take the time to become familiar with it.  It's not going to be fun for anyone involved if you have to keep asking others questions any time a small issue comes up.

Comment: I got it Taplar. I'm not going to be using JS alot. I'm just trying. I'm learning a bit everyday. It's a small problem to you, but to me it's a big one. But thanks for the feedback. I'll try to get more into it before I as a question again, even though I did nsearched A LOT on the forum and didn't get it alone, so sory for being dumb to this point. eLy

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible solutions based on your requirement.
Start: 11AM, End: 9AM

If you want the output to be 2 hours,

```
var diff = Math.abs(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime());
```

If you want the output to be 22 hours,

```
var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    if (diff < 0) {
        diff += 24 * 1000 * 60 * 60;
    }
```

Comment: I need it to be, for example, start at 00:00 and end at 08:00 the result woule be 8 hours. But if the start time is 20:00 and the end time is 01:00 (am) it should be 5 hours and not 0-19:00 like it shows

Comment: Great, that's why I put 2 solutions. :)