# My JavaScript Function is does not calculate the hours

Tags: javascript, function

**This is My JavaScript code**

```
    function date(){
    var starth = document.getElementById("stime").vlue;
    
    var endh= document.getElementById("etime").value;  
    var duration = parseFloat(endh) - parseFloat(starth);
    var noOfDays = Math.floor(duration / (1000*60*60*24));
    var noOfHours = Math.floor(duration % (1000*60*60*24) / (1000*60*60));
    var noOfMinutes = Math.floor(duration % (1000*60*60) / (1000*60));
    var noOfSeconds = Math.floor(duration % (1000*60) / 1000);

    
    document.getElementById("tlecture").value =  noOfHours + "hours" + noOfMinutes + "minutes" + noOfSeconds + "seconds";
   
}
```

**This is My Form**

```
 <form class="form-inline" method="post">
          
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Lecture Name: </label> <br>
                    <br> <input type="text" id="search-box" name="search-box"  size="60"   />
                    <div id="suggesstion-box" align="center" ></div>

                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cname">Course Name: </label></br>
                    <br> <input type="text" id="search-box_2"  name="search-box_2" required placeholder="Search By Name..." size="60"  />
                    <div id="suggesstion-box_2" align="center"></div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="stime">Start Time: </label></br>
                    <br> <input type="time" id="status" name="stime"  size="60"  required="true" />
                    <label for="etime">End Time: </label></br>
                    <br> <input type="time" id="etime" name="etime"  size="60"  required="true" />
            

                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cname">Total Lecture : </label></br>
                  
                    <br> <input type="text" id="tlecture"  name="tlecture"  size="60"  />
               
                    <button  class="btn btn-primary" name="submit"  onclick="date()"> Calculate</button>

                </div>
            
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" style=" position: absolute; bottom: 62%;"> Submit </button>

            </form>
```

My Javascript function is not working. When I click the calculate button, I want to get the total hours the lecture has worked. The lecture can enter the start time and end time from the form. I wrote a function to calculate the total hours but it's not working. I try to debug via console but nothing showed in the console. Can someone help me out?  I want to enter the start time and end time after that I want to calculate the total hours.

Comment: Pay close attention in the browser's debugging tools.  When you press the button, is the page being reloaded?

Comment: `endh` and `starth` are elements - you cannot do `endh - starth` so your `duration` will be wrong

Comment: Since you're trying to assign the calculation value to an `input`, you should be using `value` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: @EI_Vanja I changed the code from innerHTML to value but nothing shows.

Comment: @David Yes It is

Comment: @HavishkaHalangoda: Then the first thing to do would be to make the button `type="button"` so it doesn't submit the form by default (the default is `type="submit"`).  Though as noted by other comments there appear to be multiple problems to solve here.

Comment: @Pete I changed the code and use 'value' after the endh and starth but nothing works

Comment: you probably also need to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` otherwise your value will be treated as text

Comment: @Pete I tried that solution also

Comment: When I click Calculate it shows NaN

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between two html time inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54658859/difference-between-two-html-time-inputs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
   function date(){
            p = "1/1/1970 ";
            var starth = document.getElementById("stime").value;
            var endh= document.getElementById("etime").value;
           var difference = new Date(new Date(p+endh) - new Date(p+starth)).toUTCString().split(" ")[4];
            document.getElementById("tlecture").value =  difference;


        }
</script>
```

Here is the answer for my question. This is the correct calculation